# Putting divs and images side by side with text below each image

Tags: html, css, image, division

I have two images that I am putting in separate divs, and I want to put the text below each image respectively. However, for everything that I have tried it's not working right.

Here is my code so that you could let me know what I am doing wrong.

HTML

```html
<div class="eldersaac">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img"> <img src="Elder.jpg" id="elder" />
      <h3>Elder Priest Esaias Ben YAHUDAH Y'ISRAEL</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="img"> <img src="Isaac.jpg" id="saac" />
      <h3>Isaac Ben YAHUAH Y'ISRAEL</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Share your css code too

Comment: Thanks for answering athimohan. This is my first time using stackoverflow to post a question. Where do I go to add my code?

Comment: The system is telling me it's too long when I put it in the comment box.

Comment: I'm going to have to send it piece by piece if that's ok.

Comment: Please use the snippet for html/css/js code https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made up an example using your HTML code.

```css
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.img{ float:left; width:50%; text-align:center;}
.img img{ width:100%;}
.img h3{ display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="eldersaac">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400/ff0/000a96&text=Dummy+Image" id="elder" />
      <h3>Elder Priest Esaias Ben YAHUDAH Y'ISRAEL</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="img"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400/0f0/000a96&text=Dummy+Image" id="saac" />
      <h3>Isaac Ben YAHUAH Y'ISRAEL</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's helpful for you:

```css
.img{
width:45%;
float:left;
margin-left:2%;
position:relative;
}
img{max-width:100%;}

.img h3{font-size:12px; position:absolute;width:100%; bottom:0px; padding:5px 0px; background:#000; color:#fff; margin:0px}
```

```html
<div class="eldersaac">
<div class="container">
<div class="img"> 
<img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/27yo6s8.jpg" id="elder" />
<h3>Elder Priest Esaias Ben YAHUDAH </h3>
</div> 
<div class="img"> 
<img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/27yo6s8.jpg" id="elder" />
<h3>Ben YAHUAH Y'ISRAE</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```